# httpclient use in calling an wep api

Tags: identityserver4

In the example provided on the IS4 website for calling a web API (the function CallApiUsingUserAccessToken), it creates at each request a HTTP client. I read on the web that you can run into problems if too many requests are received by the server using this method.

Is any way we can declare static the http client and assign the bearer token somehow differently ?

If I declare static httpclient and use SetBearerToken extension, theoretically my token can be used by a subsequent request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a shared HttpClient, you need to create the HttpRequestMessage yourself and set the header on each message.

Then use the SendAsync method to send your message.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138176(v=vs.118).aspx